# Make [welfare] a tag synonym of [social-welfare]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

[welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welfare) has 9 questions, [social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare) has 24 questions. They are basically the same, so it makes sense to make one the synonym of the other. I suggest keeping [social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare) as the main tag because it is a bit more informative (e.g. avoiding confusion with subsidies, a term that is used for government money supporting businesses).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare):

> Welfare is a type of government support for the citizens of that society.

And above that it reads (like a comment):

> "Social welfare" redirects here. For conceptual models of societal well-being, see Social welfare function.

Comment: Are you going to revisit this now that you’re a mod?

Comment: @EkadhSingh I don't think this question has been considered enough for me to push the change on my own. Which of the two should be the main tag? Feel free to write an answer saying what you think, that way it should get some more views / comments too. Specifically, I think some questions don't fit well with [tag:social-welfare], for example there's a [tag:welfare] question about farm subsidies. (How) should that be retagged?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make [welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welfare) a synonym of [social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare).

The following, as I see it, shows the specialization (for classifying questions) that applies to [public-funding](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-funding).

| Main tag | Sub-tag | Sub-sub-tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [public-funding](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-funding) |  |  |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare) |  |
| ┃ | ┣╾╾╾╾ | [social-security](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-security) |
| ┃ | ┣╾╾╾╾ | [basic-income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-income) |
| ┃ | ┗╾╾╾╾ | Non-specific social-welfare |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [subsidies](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsidies) |  |
| ┣╾╾╾╾ | [stimulus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stimulus) |  |
| ┗╾╾╾╾ | Non-specific public-funding |  |

---

From [a comment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/make-welfare-a-tag-synonym-of-social-welfare#comment13610_3886):

> Specifically, I think some questions don't fit well with social-welfare, for example there's a welfare question about farm subsidies. (How) should that be retagged?

Remove the [welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welfare) tag. Subsidies, whether agricultural, manufacturing or other, are "public funding" rather than welfare, as shown above.

Comment: So what's the idea of [public-funding]? Do we add that in addition to [subsidies] / [social-welfare], only if there's room for another tag or only when we don't use a more specific subtag?

Comment: I would say to use [public-funding] only when asking about spending for areas not otherwise covered; such as, [climate-change]. For example, *How much is government spending on climate change?* could use [public-funding] + [climate-change]. Whereas, *How much is government spending on agricultural subsidies?* would use [agriculture] + [subsidies], but would not use the [public-funding] tag because such subsidies are public funding.

Comment: Yea makes sense. In that case the [public-funding] tag excerpt should probably mention the related subtags as well.

Comment: As another example, questions about the US WIC or TANF programs would use [social-welfare] but not [public-funding] even when asking about spending because the programs are publicly funded.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't approved the synonym previously. I will do that now and then merge them. Still, I noticed these two questions are tagged [welfare] when they are actually about some happiness index. I'll leave them alone for now because I don't know what other tags might be appropriate. These questions are: [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/41357) and [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8331).

Comment: @JJJ - I think replace [tag:social-welfare] with [tag:society]. A "happiness index" would be an [tag:indicators] of the feelings of well-being of a society. I had considered [tag:psychology] since it deals with mind and behavior, but its seems to be a stretch.